# Ruby: TouchAction:move_to

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to implement below `move_to` action
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/appium_lib/9.3.8/Appium%2FTouchAction:move_to

`Appium::TouchAction.new.press(x: 176, y: 200).move_to(50).perform`

but it is giving error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `key?' for 100:Integer
```

I want to move/swipe screen on iOS Simulator from one co-ordinates to other co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you posted clearly states that `move_to` expects a hash with `:x` and `:y` as parameters, just like you passed to `press`.

```rb
Appium::TouchAction.new.press(x: 176, y: 200).move_to(x: 176, y: 200).perform
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for TouchAction is as follows (in python):

```
touch = TouchAction(driver)
touch.press(x=473, y=1396).move_to(x=468, y=705).release().perform()
```

The syntax remains the same for ruby with paramenters for `press` and `move_to` class